How can I type navigation for reusable screens inside multiple stack navigators?
I'm using React Navigation and would like to achieve type safety for navigating between screens.
I have multiple tabs in a tab navigator, each tab is a stack navigator. Each stack navigator may share common screens such as Profile or Post. I want to navigate between these two screens, but stay in the appropriate tab.
My current code, which works, but is not type safe, is as follows:
// Create two stack navigator types, representing the two tabs of my tab navigator
export type SearchStackParamList = {
  PostScreen: PostScreenParams;
  ProfileScreen: ProfileScreenParams;
};

export type NewsfeedStackParamList = {
  PostScreen: PostScreenParams;
  ProfileScreen: ProfileScreenParams;
};

// Create my tab navigator
export type RootTabParamList = {
  NewsfeedStainck: NavigatorScreenParams<NewsfeedStackParamList>;
  SearchStack: NavigatorScreenParams<SearchStackParamList>;
};
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

Now I can navigate from one screen to another with navigation.navigate('Post'). The desired behavior of staying within the current stack navigator is also achieved.
However, I've been unable to figure out how to achieve type safety for this. How can I do that?
